# What is the maximum frequency for magnetometerUpdateInterval?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-motion, magnetometer

What is the maximum frequency for magnetometerUpdateInterval? i cannot find any Apple documentation over this or posts about this.  I know for the accelerometer it peaks around 107 Hz and for the gyroscope it peaks around 76 Hz.  However, I fear that the magnetometer will be a lot less than this do to it settling to the magnetic field.

Comment: Did you ever come up with an approximate number?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/magnetometerUpdateInterval) the frequency is capped at a maximum value determined by the hardware capabilities of the device.

> The value of this property is capped to minimum and maximum values; the maximum value is determined by the maximum frequency supported by the hardware. If your app is sensitive to the intervals of magnetometer data, it should always check the timestamps of the delivered CMMagnetometerData instances to determine the true update interval.

Comment: Yes I saw this.  I should have been more clear. how about for either the iphone 4s, iphone 5, iphone 5s, ipad 3, ipad 4, ipad mini or ipad air?  Any of them.

Comment: My impression is that the software makes a judgement based on whatever hardware it is running on.  I don't know that anyone has published a chart of "predicted" intervals.